# Can not run Java 1.8 compiled class on Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run some test classes on Hadoop cluster using Spark. This is the command I am using:

```
sudo spark-submit --class "Test" --master yarn spark-proj-1.0.jar
```

This is the error I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   Test : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

The error is supposed to mean the classes were compiled with a higher Java version than the one used to run them. I compiled the classes using Java 1.8, I have Spark 1.3 installed on the cluster. I had Java 1.7 installed, but have since installed 1.8 on all nodes. `java -version` command shows me I am indeed using Java 1.8:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you build Spark 1.3 yourself or downloaded ?

Comment: I installed it with Bigtop ...

Comment: Did you verify (ps) that yarn is actually launching containers with Java 1.8?

Comment: Can you write me a command for this?